# PHP display events at the exact date

Tags: php

I have a website with a list of events and I want to improve it with a section that will display events that will take place today, this week and this month, so it's a section divided into 3.

I suddenly have a question, I don't know if this is possible, because I have for example events that will last several months, which means that this event will be displayed all the time in the "today" section and this is not the desired result.

I would like to display the events that will take place today only, and which will end tomorrow only, is this possible to do?

there is my part of code to filter events:

```
        switch ($period) {
            case 'today':
                // Event available today
                $extendedParams[] = array(
                    'id'     => 'optionFilter',
                    'params' => array(
                        'classes'    => array('template_event'),
                        'attribute'  => 'date_end',
                        'comparison' => '>=',
                        'field'      => 'data_int',
                        'value'      => $tempTime,
                    ),
                );
                break;
            case 'week':
                // Event available until next week
                $extendedParams[] = array(
                    'id'     => 'optionFilter',
                    'params' => array(
                        'classes'    => array('template_event'),
                        'attribute'  => 'date_end',
                        'comparison' => '>=',
                        'field'      => 'data_int',
                        'value'      => strtotime('next monday'),
                    ),
                );
                break;
            case 'next':
            case 'month':
                // Event available until next month
                $extendedParams[] = array(
                    'id'     => 'optionFilter',
                    'params' => array(
                        'classes'    => array('template_event'),
                        'attribute'  => 'date_end',
                        'comparison' => '>=',
                        'field'      => 'data_int',
                        'value'      => strtotime('midnight last day of this month'),
                    ),
                );
                break;

            default:
                return array();
        }
```

Comment: Yes of course its possible. Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful, and a view of your expected output based on the table data you show as an example.
If at all possible create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: In general it is indeed possible to read data, perform logic, and display data.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I edited my question with a part of code, that's what I tried,  I can see for exemple events start at 1 april and end at 30 june at the "today" section, and I want to display only events start for exemple at 31 may and end at 01 june

Comment: Where do you get `$period` from. You are going to need to look at the start date and end date to be able to get what you want

Comment: $period is a param of my func, which contain theses periods : (today/week/month/next)
I have access to my start and end date but I don't know how can I filter like I want

Comment: Show us some sample data, then maybe we can help